# D3 Selection always returns all items after enter() regardless of whether they are new or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

**For context: I am running D3 inside a React application, and tying the D3 update pattern to the React lifecycle methods.**

**The Problem:**
When I `const selection = select(".svg-circle-node-class").data(nodeArray)`, D3 always provides me EVERY node in the array, EVERY TIME the function is run, regardless of whether new Nodes have been added to the array or not. I expect the function `selection.enter()` to provide me with NEW nodes, and `selection.exit()` to provide me the non-existent nodes for removal, and for any operations done directly on this selection without using `enter()` should provide me with all the remaining nodes, like so:

[image: D3 selection Venn diagram]

This issue leads me to be unable to differentiate between new and old items and this result in me always re-appending new SVG elements, therefore duplicating everything every time there's a state change. I want to just update values of these elements instead.

My specific situation is the following: I have an implementation of a Graph, structured like so:

```ts
class Graph {
  nodes: Node[];
}

class DirectedEdge {
  from: Node;
  to: Node;
}

class Node {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  edges: DirectedEdge[];
  id: string; // unique for each node
}
```

And in my react component, I am tracking the state of the graph by saving an instance of it in the component state, like so:

```ts
const n1, n2: Node = ...;

interface IState {
  g: Graph = new Graph(n1, n2), // constructor connects two graphs with an edge
  degree: number // a parameter to change some shapes
}
```

And I tied the initialization of the chart to the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, and here's the function for doing that:

```ts
    /** Once HTML elements have loaded, this method is run to initialize the SVG elements using D3. */
    private initializeGraph(): void {
        const mainGroup = select(this.svgElement.current)
            .append("g")
            .attr("id", "main");

        // append nodes svg group
        this.nodeElements = mainGroup.append("g")
            .attr("id", "nodes")
            .selectAll<SVGCircleElement, Node>(".directed-graph-node")
            .data<Node>(this.state.g.nodes, _ => _.id);

        // append edges svg group
        this.edgeElements = mainGroup.append("g")
            .attr("id", "edges")
            .selectAll<SVGPathElement, DirectedEdge>(".directed-graph-edge")
            .data<DirectedEdge>(this.state.g.nodes.flatMap(_ => _.edges), _ => _.id);

    }
```

And I tied an `updateGraph` function to the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function, causing it to be called every time there's a change to the state (i.e., in this case, caused by the parameter 'degree' changing. But I want to be able to update the (x,y) positions of each node at every update as well).

```ts
private updateGraph(): void {
        if (!this.nodeElements || !this.edgeElements) return;

        console.log("before", this.nodeElements, this.edgeElements);

        // select nodes & edges
        const graphNodes = this.nodeElements
            .data<Node>(this.state.g.nodes, _ => _.id);
        const graphEdges = this.edgeElements
            .data<DirectedEdge>(this.state.g.nodes.flatMap(_ => _.edges), _ => _.id);

        console.log("after", graphNodes, graphEdges);

        // update nodes with their current position
        graphNodes.attr("cx", node => node.x)
            .attr("cy", node => node.y);

        // add newly added nodes if any
        graphNodes.enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", ".directed-graph-node")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("cx", node => node.x)
            .attr("cy", node => node.y)
            .attr("r", 2.5)
            .call(drag<SVGCircleElement, Node>());

        // remove nodes that don't exist anymore
        graphNodes.exit().remove();

        // add ID of node
        graphNodes.append("text")
            .attr("x", node => node.x)
            .attr("y", node => node.y)
            .attr("font-size", 3)
            .text(d => d.id);

        // function to draw edge
        const drawEdge = (edge: DirectedEdge, context: Path): Path => {
            const {from, to} = edge;

            context.moveTo(from.x, from.y);
            
            // some math is done and some lines are drawn here

            return context;
        };

        // add new edges
        const edgeGroupOnEnter = graphEdges.enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", ".directed-graph-edge");

        // remove old unused edges
        graphEdges.exit().remove();

        // update path of unchanged edges
        graphEdges.attr("d", edge => drawEdge(edge, path()).toString())

        // draw new edges
        edgeGroupOnEnter.append("path")
            .attr("stroke", "red")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("d", edge => drawEdge(edge, path()).toString());

        // add midpoint for debug
        edgeGroupOnEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("stroke", "red")
            .attr("cx", edge => edge.from.midpoint(edge.to).x)
            .attr("cy", edge => edge.from.midpoint(edge.to).y)
            .attr("r", 0.5);

    }
```

Does anyone have a clue where I am messing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In D3, you have to perform the data join again if you want to get the **new** enter/update/exit selections. What happens in your code is:

- You do a data join *once* in your `initialize` function (for each of your chart elements). That data join marks every node as new and returns every node, and you then cache those results.
- In your `update` function, you use those cached results every time.

Instead, perform the data join on `update`, every time the graph changes, instead of on `initialize`. An example with `nodeElements`:

```
private initializeGraph(): void {
    const mainGroup = select(this.svgElement.current)
        .append("g")
        .attr("id", "main");

    // append nodes svg group
    this.nodeElements = mainGroup.append("g")
        .attr("id", "nodes")
}

private updateGraph(): void {
    // select nodes & edges
    const graphNodes = this.nodeElements
        .selectAll<SVGCircleElement, Node>(".directed-graph-node")
        .data<Node>(this.state.g.nodes, _ => _.id);

    // update nodes with their current position
    graphNodes.attr("cx", node => node.x)
        .attr("cy", node => node.y);

    // add newly added nodes if any
    graphNodes.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", ".directed-graph-node")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("cx", node => node.x)
        .attr("cy", node => node.y)
        .attr("r", 2.5)
        .call(drag<SVGCircleElement, Node>());

    // remove nodes that don't exist anymore
    graphNodes.exit().remove();
}
```

As you can see, this pattern is pretty heavy-handed. We can use [selection.join()](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join) instead. It allows us to remove the duplicate code on `enter` and `update` and be less heavy.

```
private updateGraph(): void {
    const graphNodes = this.nodeElements
        .selectAll<SVGCircleElement, Node>(".directed-graph-node")
        // data() join()
        .data<Node>(this.state.g.nodes, _ => _.id)
        .join(
        enter => enter.append("circle")
            .attr("class", ".directed-graph-node")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("r", 2.5)
            .call(drag<SVGCircleElement, Node>()),
        update => update,
        exit => exit.remove();
        )
        // enter + update past this point
        .attr("cx", node => node.x) 
        .attr("cy", node => node.y)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, Hugo. I indeed fundamentally misunderstood the meaning of a data join. Have a good one.